# Thunderbird addressbook unable to search entire fields at a time

Tags: thunderbird

I have been migrated to Thunderbird. When you want to search the address book, for example you have cell phone field, and you input query for it, it can't search in cell phone. If I want to search that, I have to select advanced search and select my field.

How can I search this without going to advanced search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.)

In main menu for address book go to:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced
```

Or in main mail window go by menu:

```
[=]
 |
 +----> Preferences -> Preferences
```

Here select tab *General* and click <kbd>Config editor ...</kbd> and confirm that you are going to be careful.

### 2.)

Type in `attr` in the filter field at top, there you find

```
ldap_2.servers.default.attrmap.CellularNumber
```

OK. That is the Name to use: **`CellularNumber`**.

### 3.)

Now enter:

```
mail.addr_book.quicksearchquery.format
```

in the filter box and edit the value. It would typically become something like:

> ?(or(PrimaryEmail,c,@V)(CellularNumber,c,@V)(DisplayName,c,@V)(FirstName,c,@V)(LastName,c,@V))

That is: *PrimaryEmail or CellularNumber or DisplayName or ...*

---

If you have the address book open close it and open it again to get the change.

---

#### In addition or instead of:

If you frequently search contacts you might find it useful to install some contacts addon. Did a quick search and installed this one: *[Contact Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/contact-tabs/?src=cb-dl-toprated)*

It gives you search in main window where you can select filtering by:

- Emails, Names, Organizations
- Addresses
- Phone and Fax numbers
- Notes and Custom fields

---

#### By script

If you administer several computers (e.g. in an office environment), or simply for fun/educational purpose/etc. you can also use scripts to auto configure. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MCD,_Mission_Control_Desktop_AKA_AutoConfig) and here

- [Configuration utilities for administrators](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Configuration_utilities_for_administrators)
- [http://web.mit.edu/~thunderbird/www/maintainers/autoconfig.html](http://web.mit.edu/%7Ethunderbird/www/maintainers/autoconfig.html)